# Vue js cambiar data desde method

Tags: vue.js, data

Quiero actualizar unos datos que recibo en una de las funciones de method pero me está siendo imposible averiguar que me falla

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            user: {
                name: 'Nombre',
                email: 'Emilio',
                img: 'url de la imagen'
            },
            name: 'Marco',
            usuario: null,

        },
        created: function () {
            this.initFirebase(),
            this.auth()

        },
        methods: {
            initFirebase: function () {
                // Your web app's Firebase configuration
                var firebaseConfig = {
                      xxxxxxxx
                };
                // Initialize Firebase
                firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            },
            auth: function () {
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (userData) {
                    console.log(userData);
                    this.name = userData.displayName;

                    }

                });
            }
        },
    })
```

En la consola imprimo userData y me sale todo bien, no me sale ningún fallo. No se si es problema de declarar antes unas cosas que otras. Cualquier ayuda buena es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando utilizas una `function` el `this` cambia, te presento dos tipos de soluciones pero te recomiendo la primera

1. Utilizar arrow functions

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((userData) => {
    console.log(userData);
    this.name = userData.displayName;
}
```

2. Declarar this en otra variable

```
let self = this;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (userData) {
    console.log(userData);
    self.name = userData.displayName;
}
```